# Is there an API available to download a digital product?

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable, soap-api-v2

Magento provides a rich set of SOAP api calls to interact. Just wondering is there an API available to provide the customer Id and download a digital product under that customers account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, This type of soap api is not available in default magento. if you require, then create a custom API.

**Please follow the step given in below link.**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

Answer (score 0):

Check Magento catalog API details here 
[Magento Soap API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalog.html)

You can check product_downloadable_link API method  here [product_downloadable_link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductDownloadableLink/product_downloadable_link.list.html)

Comment: I guess this doesn't solve my problem. This just provides the URL but what I need to download the product by providing a customer id. Also the download counter of that customer should also get increment by 1

Comment: @Malaiselvan yes this is just example for your case you need to create module which will do that